# "Save for Enterprise Distribution" as ipa file, does it install in any device?

Tags: ios, ipa, code-signing-entitlements

Suppose I have enterprise account and when I "*Save for Enterprise Distribution*" as ipa file, does ipa will install in any device? 
Irrespective of Apple Id of end user is unknown ?

In other words, in which case the app will install and when it won't ?

I have went through [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html)
But I am not able to find explanation of how target devices are linked to iPA file? In case ad hoc, I know its via UUID of device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will, but for using it, you will need the user to trust your enterprise account in their Setting - General - Device Management

Also you will need a server to distribute the app, the user will be able to install through safari

Some docs to help you can be find:

1. [Distributing Apple Developer Enterprise Program Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html)
2. [Guidelines for installing custom enterprise apps on iOS](https://support.apple.com/en-vn/HT204460)

Comment: Thanks, That's a good news :-)  And Last question , can we distribute the app via ipa file ? Without any host/swebsite/link ? Just clean ipa file ?

Comment: Yes, you can also install via iTunes